# Radical of the sum of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (not necessarily with a unit), $M$ be some $R$-module, and N a submodule of the module M. We define (according to Zariski and Samuel, 1958) the radical $\sqrt N$ of the submodule N as the set $\tau$ of all elements $a \in R$, some $n$-th power each of which satisfies the relation $a^n \dot M \subset N$. $\tau$ is obviously the ideal in $R$.

Is it true that $\sqrt{M_1 + M_2} = \sqrt {\sqrt M_1 + \sqrt M_2}$, where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are submodules of $M$? And if not, what is the counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy counterexample is the 2-dimensional vector space M with basis $\{е_1, е_2\}$ and the subspaces $М_1$ and $М_2$ generated by $\{е_1\}$ and $\{е_2\}$, respectively.